# Shopware 6 problem with compiling storefront using command ./bin/build-storefront.sh in production server

Tags: node.js, npm, shopware6

I have developed a plugin for Shopware 6 and I used an external library and installed it using npm.
My development envirenment is Docker (Dockware). In Docker the npm and nodejs is already installed, so I can easily run the comman ./bin/build-storefront.sh and compile the javascript.
The plugin works in my development envirenmet after I install the Plugin and run this command.

But as soon as I install it in my Test Server, that is actually a one to one copy of our production and on the same VPS Provider, it does not work. It seems that, if I want to install it on a new Server, I have to compile it again and again.

The Problem ist, that on our Production Server, the NodeJS and NPM are not installed because of security reasons (VPS provider says).

My question is : How can I compile it on production server without Nodejs and NPM installed. Or should it work when I compile it on my development server and make a zip data and install it on the new server and it should work? (I have done that actually and it does not work as well).

I will be happy for any help and advices.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel like you have to compile assets on your production server? You, the plugin developer, should compile the assets once before you deploy/ship them with your plugin. The pre-compiled assets will be stored in `YourPlugin/src/Resources/public`. You should include them in your deployment to production. If you were to release your plugin in the official community store for example, you'd actually be required to include the pre-compiled assets, for the exact reason, that nodejs is not a requirement for production environments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I know that I don't need compile it again in production, but the problem ist, without compiling it does not work. I mean I compile it in my local computer, then I can see that it creates a js file in  `MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/dist/storefront/js/my-plugin-name.js`.
It creates no public directory. 

After I compile the plugin, I make a zip file and install it on another Server. Is it right or should I have to do something manully. I mean copy something somewhere manually?

Comment: For example I implemented exactly what SHopware in its documentation has. I mean about NPM in this [link](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-npm-dependencies). It works in my development Server after I compile it, but after I create a zip file and install it in another instance in Docker or our Test Server, it does not work.

Comment: Compiled storefront assets go to `dist`, admin assets go to `public`. Same principle. And yes, you have to copy those pre-compiled assets to the server. You can't compile any assets without nodejs, so it's the only option.

Comment: Thanks again for you answer. So as you said, pre-compiled assets should work on the server without compiling it again. For example a normal user will install it from frontend and he/she does not have any info about programming. It should work. 
Sorry, I am new in Shopware because of that some points are not clear for me. 
I have done this:
Created a plugin->add some custom javascript(only some consol.log)->added npm paclages as in docs given->compiled it->make a zip data from the whole plugin folder. 
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, sounds right.

Comment: But it does not work :-(. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you upload new or changed pre-compiled assets of the plugin you have to re-install or update the plugin for the changes to take effect. Either in the extension manager of the administration or via [CLI](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-base-guide#install-your-plugin).

Comment: This is clear, that I have to update the plugin, when I change something in Plugin. But the problem ist not in this stage, the problem is, that after installation, Shopware can not run Javascript properly.